# Elasticsearch backup to S3 using AWS Cloud plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, backup, elasticsearch-plugin

I recently started using elasticsearch together with logstash to setup an ELK stack for my servers.

I'm using this plugin here:

And I tried to simply create a repository to backup my snapshots of my indices:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/es_backup' -d '{
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
            "bucket": "keyless-elasticsearch-backup",
    }
}'
```

And I'm getting this:

`{"error":"RepositoryVerificationException[[es_backup] [i3KNe8D_Sh6UYwo2JwomwQ, 'RepositoryVerificationException[[es_backup] store location [myproj-elasticsearch-backup] is not shared between node [[Empath][i3KNe8D_Sh6UYwo2JwomwQ][myPC][inet[/192.168.2.125:9300]]] and the master node]']]]","status":500}`

I googled it a lot, but nothing comes up with anyone else having the same problem like me.

First of all, I don't really understand the error. Can someone please explain what is it about and how can I fix it?

Comment: It means that not all nodes have access to the snapshot repository. For a successful snapshot, the repository must be accessible by all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: And how can I do that? Do I have to configure something in `elasticsearch.yml` or provide some setting in my request?

Comment: @AndreiStefan could you point me in the right direction to fix this? Also, as a side note: The repositories get created anyways. When I GET http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/, I see my repos. And then I'm able to create snapshots to those repos too. I can see the indices in my S3 bucket.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? @bad_keypoints